# What does the PaperBin property represent for a printer?

Tags: printing, vb6

I am trying to print to a specific tray of a given printer from my application.
My code works for certain printers and does not for some others.

Can anyone tell me if the Tray id of the printer is the same as the Paperbin.
I came across this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245866(v=vs.60).aspx which says that paperbin value is always between 1 to 14.

However, when I see my printer tray id using a tool, I see it to be 259.
Is it a valid tray id?
[image]